# include shipping method in VAT calculation

Tags: tax, vat

i'm using magento CE 1.8.0.1, and i'm struggling with this issue:

if i order a product at 75€, then choose a shipping method in the checkout process, i want the tax to be calculated on the product price + the shipping method price. Actually, only the product price is considered.

Here's my tax configuration :
[image]

I tried many combinations before going back to my default settings, but i never got the shipping method price to get included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup under Sales > Tax > Tax Classes
--Taxable Goods
--Shipping

Setup under Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules

In you rules have you checked: "Product tax classes" both classes for "Taxable Goods" and "Shipping"?

Are you using custom template? If yes then compare file corresponding to estimated shipping block (checkout/cart/shipping.phtml) with default template - there's code for displaying both prices.

If nothing helps, try to setup to display both prices for shipping - Including and Excluding (maybe you have your excluding shipping cost setup with wrong value) if not then different cost should be displayed.

P.S. My Tax configuration: 
[image]

Comment: I'm using a custom product tax class i named "TVA", representing 20% of my product's price for france. I'm using a template i made, but i was always starting from the core files while i was developing.

the "Shipping" tax class wasn't selected in my tax rules, but it doesn't seems to change anything on my order summary

Comment: Did you changed on Configuration > Tax the first option:
From:
Tax Class for Shipping: None

into 

Tax Class for Shipping: Shipping? (just like in your screenshot), you can also try choosing there the TVA rate which's equal into 20% (if the goods are at same tax rate as shipping) .

Comment: Don't forget to add "Shipping" product tax class in your TAX RULES.

Comment: okay, i still don't get the right calculation (most probably an including vs exluding tax settings at some point), but now my tax price increase when i set a shipping method. I was missing both "select shipping in the tax rule" and the first option on my configuration. I was struggling with this from soo long, many thanks to both of you.

Comment: Please post a simple screenshot with an example on cart - I could see what's calculating which rows :)

Comment: Even the calculation is right, i was checking the calculation by applying tax to already taxed products yesterday. Can't believe it was so simple, i really searched for some documentation but couldn't find these tips anywhere. Next time i'll explore the back-office meticulously. Thanks again